# scala compile error: type mismatch; found: IndexedSeq[Int] required: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int]

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I don't know why the following scala code can not be compiled:

```scala
import collection.immutable.Seq
def foo(nodes: Seq[Int]) = null
val nodes:IndexedSeq[Int] = null
foo(nodes)
```

=>

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : IndexedSeq[Int]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int]
             foo(nodes)
                 ^
```

In scala-library, IndexedSeq is declared:

```scala
trait IndexedSeq[+A] extends Seq[A]...
```

Comment: Oh. Because there are several IndexedSeq traits. Default is scala.collection.IndexedSeq. if I import collection.immutable.IndexedSeq then scala will compile successfully

Comment: Post that as an answer for the benefit of other users :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several IndexedSeq traits. Default is `scala.collection.IndexedSeq`. if you `import collection.immutable.IndexedSeq` then scala will compile successfully. (Copied from OP)